# Rails 3: How to solve an inconsistency in date format in development and production environments?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, date-format

My `Job` model has `job_date` field that is defined in the migration file like this:

```
create_table :jobs do |t|
  t.date "job_date", :null => false
  [...]
end
```

In my development environment (on Windows), when I do:

```
job = Job.new(:job_date => "17/04/2011")
```

everything works fine (i.e. the `job_date` is set properly), while when I do:

```
job = Job.new(:job_date => "04/17/2011")
```

`job_date` is set to `nil`.

I guess this is because the database (MySQL) expects to get the date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format.

The problem is that in my production environment, exactly the opposite occurs, i.e.:

```
job = Job.new(:job_date => "04/17/2011")
```

sets the 'job_date` properly, while:

```
job = Job.new(:job_date => "17/04/2011")
```

sets it to `nil`.

How could I solve this inconsistency ?

Is there some way to config the database for specific date format (like `DD/MM/YYYY`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a database problem, but I think it is a problem with `Date.parse` method in Ruby. Infact when you call `Job.new` it is not saved to database only a new object of the model is created. I beleive Rails call `Date.parse` method to convert the string into date object and it gives a error for `dd/mm/yyyy` format in my machine

```
Date.parse("17/04/2011")
=> ArgumentError: invalid date
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:956:in `new_by_frags'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1000:in `parse'
    from (irb):3
```

I think Rails escape this error and gives `nil` for such values

```
job = Job.new(:job_date => "17/04/2011")
job.job_date
=> nil

job = Job.new(:job_date => "04/17/2011")
job.job_date
=> Sun, 17 Apr 2011
```

I guess your production environment's results are same like my machine and your development machine's Ruby, `Date.parse` may be working for the other format.

If you need to handle only one format(Either `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`), you can use `Date.strptime` to calculate the date before giving to database

```
job_date = Date.strptime("17/04/2011", "%d/%m/%Y") # or "%m/%d/%Y"
job = Job.new(:job_date => job_date)
```

This will work both in your production and development environment for one format.

Comment: Do you mean I should have one code for development env and another code production env ? I wonder if it's possible not to split the code...

Comment: what is your requirement? is this date taken as an input from the user? Do you want to be able to accept both formats from the user?..I was saying, you can stick to any one format `%d/%m/%Y` or `%%m/%d/%Y` and do `strptime` on the correct format before creating the object so that ruby will correctly convert it before saving it to database.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I guess the problem is that the implementation of `Date.parse` has been changed since `ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]` (my production env). In my development env I have `ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32]`, where `Date.parse` works in other way.

Comment: ok..the ruby version in my machine is also `1.8.7`. So the problem is indeed with the implementation of Ruby's `Date.parse`.

Comment: Yes. Finally I used `Date.strptime` as you've suggested. Thanks for your time!